# How to apply whitespaces in pound signed string in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, whitespace, swift5

Swift 5 came up with an extra new approach to declare string literals, which is using `#` sign (before opening and closing quotes) to declare a string without worrying about *backslashes* and *quote marks*.

<sub>(Reference: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0200-raw-string-escaping.md)</sub>

For example:

```
let string1 = #"\ Hello World"#
print(string1) // => \ Hello World

let string2 = "Hello World #"
print(string2) // => Hello World #

let string3 = ##"#\#\ Hello World #\#\"##
print(string3) // => #\#\ Hello World #\#\
```

However, when attempting to use pound signs for declaring a string that contains a whitespace, it won't work. Let's consider the tab:

```
let tabString = #"Hello World\t#"#
print(tabString) // => Hello World\t#
```

My expected result is `Hello World      #` but not `Hello World\t#`.

How to resolve such an issue when using `#` declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updated Answer:

At this point, you could type it as `\#t`.

<sub>Thanks for @dan for commenting this.</sub>

---

**Old Answer:**

Logically, the result of `Hello World\t\` seems to be logical, because the purpose of using `#` for declaring a string is to "literally" deal with backslashes as backslashes, means that "\t" would be displayed as `"\t"` but not `"      "`.

As a workaround, what you could do here is to *interpolate* the whitespace in your string as a string declared without using the pound sign:

```
let tabString = #"Hello World \#("\t")#"#
print(tabString) // => Hello World     #
```

Keep in mind that when interpolating inside a `#""#` declared string, you should add `#` after the backslash (`\#("\t")` NOT `\("\t")`).

Comment: Can't you just do `\#t`?

Comment: @dan You're correct `print(#"Hello World \#t#"#)` does yield the desired output, and is the appropriate way of doing it. @AhmadF Even though the above *self-answer* does the job, it uses string interpolation with is very slow. Wouldn't consider it a quality answer.